# Como guardar datos de campos en un localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Quiero guardar los datos en un almacenamiento local de estos campos en el filtro de funciones si alguien me puede ayudar con esto
Tengo dos ajax en esta función, lo que estoy buscando es guardar los datos que estoy buscando al filtrar y que no se pierden al actualizar el sitio y que para borrarlos sea por medio de un boton. si pueden brindarme apoyo en lo que estoy haciendo mal

```
 function mostrarFiltro() {
   var res = localStorage.getItem('res');
   if (res) {
     $('#tab-1').html(res);
     $('#tab-2').html(res);
   }
}
function filter() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'example.php',
                data: { 
                    'oper'  : 'filters',
                    'id' : $("#id").val(),
                    'filter1' : $("#filter1").val(),
                    'filter2' : $("#filter2").val(),
                    'filter3' : $("#filter3").val(),
                    'filter4' : $("#filter4").val(),
                    'filter5' : $("#filter5").val(),
                    'filter6' : $("#filter6").val(),
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#Tab-1').fadeOut(500);
                    $('#Tab-1').html(response);
                    localStorage.setItem('res', response);
                    $('#Tab-1').fadeIn(500);
                },
                error: function () {
                    swal({title: "Error",text: "Oops Error", type: "error"});
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'example.php',
                data: { 
                    'oper'  : 'filters',
                    'id' : $("#id").val(),
                    'filter1' : $("#filter1").val(),
                    'filter2' : $("#filter2").val(),
                    'filter3' : $("#filter3").val(),
                    'filter4' : $("#filter4").val(),
                    'filter5' : $("#filter5").val(),
                    'filter6' : $("#filter6").val(),
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#Tab-2').fadeOut(500);
                    $('#Tab-2').html(response);
                    localStorage.setItem('res', response);
                    $('#Tab-2').fadeIn(500);
                },
                error: function () {
                    swal({title: "Error",text: "Oops Error", type: "error"});
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: en `localStorage` solo se pueden guardar string. Si la `response` no es un string, debes usar `JSON.stringify(response)` para pasarlo a string. Usa dos `keys` distintos cuando hagas `localStorage.setItem(key, data)` para no sobreesribir los valores.

Comment: podrias brindar un ejemplo detallado?

Comment: que tipo de dato es la variable `response` en el metodo `success`. Es string u objeto? Y tambien podrias indicar lo que no te funciona

Comment: el filter 1 es tipo numerico, filter 2 y 3 son tipo fecha.  filter 4 5 y 6 son selectores

Comment: es que no me queda claro lo que quieres guardar. Los filtros o los datos que te llegan del server?

Comment: los datos que filtros en los campos de filter 1 2 3 4 5 y 6

Comment: Digamos que si filtro uno de esos campos que ese dato que seleccione para filtrar se quede guardado y si refresco la pagina se mantenga ahi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He creado una función que recoge los valores de los filtros y otra para guardar los datos en `localStorage`.

```
function getFilterValues() {
    return {
      // para definir una propiedad en un objeto no es necesario usar literales ''
      'filter1': $("#filter1").val(),
      'filter2': $("#filter2").val(),
      'filter3': $("#filter3").val(),
      'filter4': $("#filter4").val(),
      'filter5': $("#filter5").val(),
      'filter6': $("#filter6").val(),
  }
}

function saveLocalStorage(key, value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

function filter() {
  // recoges los valores
  const filterValues = getFilterValues();
  // los guardas en localStorage
  saveLocalStorage('filterValues', filterValues);

// y lo envias al server
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'example.php',
    data: {
      'oper': 'filters',
      'id': $("#id").val(),
      ...filterValues // esto es spread operator te mergea las propiedades que hay  en filterValues en el data
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $('#Tab-1').fadeOut(500);
      $('#Tab-1').html(response);
      localStorage.setItem('res', response);
      $('#Tab-1').fadeIn(500);
    },
    error: function() {
      swal({
        title: "Error",
        text: "Oops Error",
        type: "error"
      });
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'example.php',
    data: {
      'oper': 'filters',
      'id': $("#id").val(),
      ...filterValues
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $('#Tab-2').fadeOut(500);
      $('#Tab-2').html(response);
      localStorage.setItem('res', response);
      $('#Tab-2').fadeIn(500);
    },
    error: function() {
      swal({
        title: "Error",
        text: "Oops Error",
        type: "error"
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: el   localStorage.setItem('res', response); lo dejaria?

Comment: En el comentario de tu pregunta has puesto que solo necesitas guardar los filtros y es lo que he respondido. Y si necesitas guardar la respuesta que te llega del server eso depende de ti:)

Comment: El filtervalues si me lo ejecuta en el localstorage pero al momento de refrescar el sitio me envia undefined y se pierde

Comment: en algun sitio tendras que hacer el get de los datos almacenados en localStorage. Lo puedes hacer en `mostrarFiltro`, es que no se cuando quieres mostrar esos datos por eso no añadi esa parte en mi respuesta.

Comment: bueno revisare esa parte muchas gracias por tu aporte Hawks

Comment: de nada. Espero que te sirva sino comenta.